# How to use useSwiper outside a Swiper instance?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper for React](https://swiperjs.com/react) to show some slides.

I'm stuck at using external buttons to navigate between slides (previous and next).

Swiper has a `useSwiper` [hook](https://swiperjs.com/react#use-swiper) that can provide programmatic access to its Swiper instance API. But it does not work.

Here's my code:

```
import { useSwiper } from 'swiper/react';

//more code

const swiper = useSwiper();

//more code

<Swiper
    modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
    navigation
    spaceBetween={20}
    slidesPerView={1}
>
    <button onClick={() => swiper.slideNext()}>Slide</button>
    {
        ads.map(ad => <SwiperSlide>
            slider explanation
        </SwiperSlide>
    )}
</Swiper>
```

And when I click the button, I receive this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slideNext')

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`useSwiper` must be used by components **inside** a `Swiper` element.

So something like the following

```js
import { useSwiper } from "swiper/react";

const SwiperButtonNext = ({ children }) => {
  const swiper = useSwiper();
  return <button onClick={() => swiper.slideNext()}>{children}</button>;
};
```

and then use that inside the `Swiper`

```js
<Swiper
  modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
  navigation
  spaceBetween={20}
  slidesPerView={1}
>
  <SwiperButtonNext>Slide</SwiperButtonNext>
  {ads.map((ad) => (
    <SwiperSlide>slider explanation</SwiperSlide>
  ))}
</Swiper>;
```

---

That is because `Swiper` creates a context and the `useSwiper` hook tries to consume that context, so it needs to be called from a child of the context provider.

Comment: Such a nice explanation at the end about contexts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It solved my problem

Comment: How can you style the buttons to be at the top of the SwiperSlides? I try to put position absolute on the SwiperButtons and force it to be at the top by adding a `top` value with CSS but then the button leaves the view for the Swiper component and is not visible anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: @OmarAguinaga simply use display:flex and flex-direction: column-reverse on your main swiper tag where you see classes like swiper-initialized. Grab this div and give these 2 styling

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `onSwiper` event for the `Swiper` component to save the swiper instance with `React.useState` and then pass this instance as a prop to swiper next/prev buttons component.

```
<Swiper                     
  onSwiper={(swiper) => setSwiperInstance(swiper)}
>
   ...slides
</Swiper>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case It's works fine like this.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const swiperRef = useRef();
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        onSwiper={(swiper) => {
          swiperRef.current = swiper;
        }}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>

      <button onClick={() => swiperRef.current.slideNext()}>
        Go to Next Slide
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to access the `swiper` instance in a separate component that did not have the context for `useSwiper()`, so I did it the old fashioned way.

Component with Swiper

```
<Swiper id={'always-be-swipin'}>...</Swiper>
```

Component without context

```
const swiper = document.querySelector('always-be-swipin').swiper
```

Comment: It's more "React"-y to use `ref`s rather than directly accessing the DOM

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to have an external buttons that can navigate the slide, the solution is that you just need to use useRef() and method slideTo() to manipulate them.

Create hooks:

```
const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
const sliderRef = useRef<any>(null);
```

Handle button behaviors (Suppose in this case total slides is 5):

```
const handleNext = () => {
    if (currentSlide < 4) {
      setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1);
    }
  };

const handlePrevious = () => {
    if (currentSlide > 0) {
      setCurrentSlide(currentSlide - 1);
    }
  };
```

Here is how you navigate them:

```
useEffect(() => {
    sliderRef.current.swiper.slideTo(currentStep, 500, false);
  }, [currentSlide]);
```

Your HTML:

```
return (
<>
  <Swiper ref="{sliderRef}">
    <SwiperSlide> Slide 1 </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide> Slide 2 </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide> Slide 3 </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide> Slide 4 </SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
    <button onClick={handlePrevious}>Previous</button>
    <button onClick={handleNext}>Next</button>
</>
);
```