# swiper-button outside container in react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, react-swiper

how can I make swiper nav outside the container in react js?

[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this

**method 1**

```
//add custom btns in some inner comp
 <i className="icon-arrow-long-right review-swiper-button-next"></i>
 <i className="icon-arrow-long-left review-swiper-button-prev"></i>
```

and next in swiper comp

```
<Swiper
    navigation={{
      nextEl: '.review-swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.review-swiper-button-prev',
    }}
 >
  </Swiper>
```

or you use this way

**method 2**

```
// some-inner-component.jsx
import { React } from 'react';
import { useSwiper } from 'swiper/react';

export default function SlideNextButton() {
  const swiper = useSwiper();

  return (
    <button onClick={() => swiper.slideNext()}>Slide to the next slide</button>
  );
}
```

more in info :
https://swiperjs.com/react#use-swiper

enjoy ;)

Comment: Be careful, by method 2 you can't place your buttons outside of the Swiper container.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71617467/7047488